# Como percorrer uma lista encadeada em java

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8, lista-encadeada

Preciso percorrer uma lista encadeada para comparar se o número que o usuário irá digitar é igual a um atributo de uma classe (médicos) que tem uma lista encadeada.

Tenho as seguintes Classes: Nó, Lista_Simples, Médicos e Sistema.

O erro está no case 2 do Sistema, estou tentando usar um atributo do tipo Nó que está em Lista_Simples para percorrer (o aux está pegando o valor de primeiro que chamei de prim), só que acredito que talvez essa não deva ser a forma correta de percorrer.

Classe Nó:

```
public class No {
    private Medicos m;
    private No prox; 

public No(Medicos me) {
    this.setM(me);
    this.setProx(null);
}
}
```

Classe Lista_Simples:

```
public class Lista_Simples {
private No prim;        //Primeiro nó
private No ult;         //Último nó
private int qntdno;     //Quantidade de nós
private No aux;

 Medicos M = new Medicos();

//Construtor
public Lista_Simples(){
    this.prim = null;    //Iniciando com null
    this.ult = null;     //Iniciando com null
    this.qntdno = 0;     //Iniciando com 0
    this.aux = this.prim;
}

//Saber se a lista é vazia, se estiver nulo então é criado o primeiro nó
public boolean listavazia () {
    return (this.prim == null);
}


public void inserirPrimeiro(Medicos p) {
    No novoNo = new No(p);
    //Se a lista não for vazia o primeiro nó também é o último
    if(this.listavazia()){
        this.ult = novoNo;
    }
    novoNo.setProx(this.prim);      //O próximo nó se tornará o primeiro nó
    this.prim = novoNo;             //O novo primeiro será novoNo
    this.qntdno++;                  //Incrementando a contagem de quantidade de nós
}
public No getAux() {
    return aux;
}

public void setAux(No aux) {
    this.aux = prim;
}

}
```

Classe Médicos:

```
public class Medicos {

private String nome;
private int crm;

public int getCrm() {
    return crm;
}

public void setCrm(int crm) {
    this.crm = crm;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
}
```

Classe Sistema:

```
  public class Sistema {
//static Pacientes P;
//Medicos m;
//m = new Medicos();
//private int crmnovo = 0;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Pacientes P = new Pacientes();
    Lista_Simples ListaPacientes = new Lista_Simples();
    Lista_Simples ListaMedicos = new Lista_Simples();


    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Escolha a ação que deseja executar:"
                + "\n1-Cadastrar Paciente"
                + "\n2-Cadastrar Médico"
                + "\n3-Editar dados do Médico");
        System.out.println("Digite o número da ação que deseja executar: ");
        Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);
        int acao = menu.nextInt();

        Medicos M = new Medicos();

        switch(acao) {
            case 1:
                int fim2 = 0;

                Scanner nomeM = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("\nDigite o nome do médico:");
                String nomemedico = nomeM.nextLine();
                M.setNome(nomemedico);
                System.out.println("\nO nome é "+M.getNome());

                Scanner crmM = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("\nDigite o CRM do médico:");
                String crm = crmM.nextLine();
                M.setNome(crm);
                System.out.println("\nO CRM é "+M.getCrm());

                do {
                    ListaMedicos.inserirPrimeiro(M);
                    fim2++;
                    break;
                }while(fim != 0);

                System.out.println(ListaMedicos.imprimirLista(M));

                break;

            case 2: 
                //Medicos M = new Medicos();
                System.out.println("\nDigite o seu CRM: ");
                Scanner editar = new Scanner(System.in);
                int crmexiste = editar.nextInt();
                //System.out.println("\n"+crmexiste);
                while (ListaMedicos.M.getCrm() != crmexiste) {
                    if (crmexiste != ListaMedicos.M.getCrm()){
                        //O ERRO ESTÁ AQUI, BASICAMENTE EU NÃO CONSIGO PERCORRER A LISTA DE MÉDICOS, TEM ALGUNS CÓDIGOS QUE COMENTEI AQUI QUE DERAM ERRADO
                        System.out.println("Erro aqui!");
                        //ListaMedicos.getAux().setProx(ListaMedicos.getAux());
                        ListaMedicos.getAux().getProx();
                        System.out.println(ListaMedicos.getAux());

                        //ListaMedicos.setAux(ListaMedicos.getAux().getProx());
                        //ListaMedicos.setAux(ListaMedicos.getAux().getProx());
                    }
                    else {
                        //M2.getListademdc().pesquisarNo(crmexiste);
                        System.out.println("\nDigite o seu CRM: ");
                        Scanner novo = new Scanner(System.in);
                        int novocrm = novo.nextInt();
                        ListaMedicos.M.setCrm(novocrm);
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Desde já obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: A sua ação "cadastrar paciente", cria um novo médico? E vc precisa usar lista encadeada ou pode resolver com outra estrutura?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vc não consegue percorrer a lista de médicos pq vc está acessando o objeto `Medicos` que está na sua `ListaSimples` e não os médicos de cada nó. Não tem necessidade de criar um médico na sua classe `ListaSimples`, portanto remova essa linha dessa classe: `Medicos M = new Medicos();`

**1) Antes de percorrer a lista de médicos, vamos preenche-la corretamente.**

Construa um objeto `Medicos` novo toda vez que vc for cadastrar um novo médico. Da forma que está ai, vc criou um objeto e está modificando-o toda vez que chama o case 1. Portanto, **mova** a sua linha `Medicos M = new Medicos();` para o início do seu `case 1`, ficando assim
Deixe o seu `case 1` assim:

**2) Percorrer a lista**

Para percorrer a lista, vc deve ir nó por nó, portanto o seu while do case 2 não irá funcionar. A sua classe Sistema com as alterações ficaria basicamente assim:

```
public class Sistema {
//static Pacientes P;
//Medicos m;
//m = new Medicos();
//private int crmnovo = 0;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Pacientes P = new Pacientes();
    Lista_Simples ListaPacientes = new Lista_Simples();
    Lista_Simples ListaMedicos = new Lista_Simples();


    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Escolha a ação que deseja executar:"
                + "\n1-Cadastrar Paciente"
                + "\n2-Cadastrar Médico"
                + "\n3-Editar dados do Médico");
        System.out.println("Digite o número da ação que deseja executar: ");
        Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);
        int acao = menu.nextInt();

        switch(acao) {
            case 1:
                int fim2 = 0;
                // LINHA MOVIDA
                Medicos M = new Medicos();

                Scanner nomeM = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("\nDigite o nome do médico:");
                String nomemedico = nomeM.nextLine();
                M.setNome(nomemedico);
                System.out.println("\nO nome é "+M.getNome());

                Scanner crmM = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("\nDigite o CRM do médico:");
                String crm = crmM.nextLine();
                M.setNome(crm);
                System.out.println("\nO CRM é "+M.getCrm());

                do {
                    ListaMedicos.inserirPrimeiro(M);
                    fim2++;
                    break;
                }while(fim != 0);

                System.out.println(ListaMedicos.imprimirLista(M));

                break;

            case 2: 
                //Medicos M = new Medicos();
                System.out.println("\nDigite o seu CRM: ");
                Scanner editar = new Scanner(System.in);
                int crmexiste = editar.nextInt();
                //System.out.println("\n"+crmexiste);

                No no = ListaMedicos.getPrim();

                // NOVO WHILE
                while (no != null && no.getMedicos().getCrm() != crmexiste) {
                    if (crmexiste != ListaMedicos.M.getCrm()){
                        //O ERRO ESTÁ AQUI, BASICAMENTE EU NÃO CONSIGO PERCORRER A LISTA DE MÉDICOS, TEM ALGUNS CÓDIGOS QUE COMENTEI AQUI QUE DERAM ERRADO
                        System.out.println("Erro aqui!");
                        //ListaMedicos.getAux().setProx(ListaMedicos.getAux());
                        ListaMedicos.getAux().getProx();
                        System.out.println(ListaMedicos.getAux());

                        //ListaMedicos.setAux(ListaMedicos.getAux().getProx());
                        //ListaMedicos.setAux(ListaMedicos.getAux().getProx());
                    }
                    else {
                        //M2.getListademdc().pesquisarNo(crmexiste);
                        System.out.println("\nDigite o seu CRM: ");
                        Scanner novo = new Scanner(System.in);
                        int novocrm = novo.nextInt();
                        ListaMedicos.M.setCrm(novocrm);
                    }
                }
                // PASSA PARA O PRÓXIMO NÓ
                no = no.getProx();
                break;

        }
    }
}
}
```

Olhando para as suas classes, vc vai precisar criar os getters utilizados em cada uma (`getProx()`, `getMedicos()` e `getPrim()`)

Dica: Tem muita coisinha ai que poderia ser melhorada e algumas boas práticas poderiam ser aplicadas, então de uma pesquisada sobre quando puder. Segue um link sobre listas encadeadas tbm que vai ajudar.

https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-estrutura-dados/listas-ligadas/

Comment: Sobre os getters eu já tenho eles, só não coloquei aqui para não ficar algo cansativo afinal podem ser gerados pela própria IDE. Como posso utilizar o Medicos M = new Medicos(); no segundo case? Aqui aparece como se fosse uma "variável local "(não sei muito bem sobre java, sei que não é uma variável e sim um objeto) do case 1

Comment: Ah sim, entendi. Vc pode deixar a declaração de M na sua classe e a inicialização do objeto no momento necessário. O importante é que seja um objeto novo, uma nova referência. Mas qual seria a necessidade de ter um novo Medico no case 2?

Comment: A sua lógica de negócio permaneceu a mesma, mas explica o que vc quer fazer quando for o case 2.

Comment: Basicamente eu tava testando como funcionava, por isso deixei como comentário ali no 2, além disso eu deixei o New Medicos no geral ali (uma espécie de global) para que pudesse usar tanto no case de cadastro quanto no de edição. Quero te agradecer, você foi paciente (já que muitos usuários costumam reclamar de descrição mal elaborada, tentei deixar a minha o mais simples e mesmo assim fui negativado, acho que posso melhorar ainda mais) e se esforçou por um problema de outra pessoa. Muito obrigado mesmo pela sua ajuda!

Comment: Entendi. O problema de deixar no geral é que vc vai trabalhar em cima do mesmo objeto sempre. Se vc não criar um novo objeto (`new Medicos()`) toda vez que for cadastrar um novo, ele vai alterar aquele objeto já existente, entendeu? Já na parte de edição vc vai precisar buscar o objeto e não criar um novo. Se estiver meio confuso ainda, avisa que eu te explico melhor. Disponha, o intuito aqui é ajudar mesmo. Abraços]